# Sum with limits as a variable with subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

How would I define a sum with limits from 1 to M{subscript i} [i.e in latex `$M_{i}$`]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M} M_{i}$` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this?

```
\[
\sum_1^{M_i} x_j
\]
```

Comment: @user3218207 What's the summation variable?